# /home/user/www file permssion

Tags: 12.04, apache2, home-directory, drupal

In `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` I made the `/home/me/www` folder my localhost location.  I have downloaded Drupal into the new `www/drupal` folder and even though I gave all permissions (`777`) Apache still can't write to it.  Do I need to make another permission change?

TO make localhost not 403, I followed the steps in: https://askubuntu.com/a/232078/25656

> sudo apt-get install acl
>   You can use man setfacl to have more info.
>
> To add permissions to Apache:
>   sudo setfacl -m d:g:www-data:X,g:www-data:X /home/me
>   sudo setfacl -m d:g:www-data:X,g:www-data:X /home/me/Dropbox
>   sudo setfacl -Rm d:g:www-data:rX,g:www-data:rX /home/me/Dropbox/Web`

**/etc/apache2/sites-available/default** → http://paste.ubuntu.com/1534943/.

Comment: Are you tried with 755? No 777 permissions, 755!!! Also, owner of /home/user/www folder must be www-data:www-data.

Comment: Could you insert the relevant lines from `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default`? What does `ls -l /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/` show`

Comment: ls -l /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/:  total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 26 Jan 14 21:34 000-default -> ../sites-available/default

Comment: 755 is not working.   Wehn I go sudo chown www-data:www-data www/  I still am not able to get the files writable via apache

Comment: Before I try, should I do this: chmod 751 "$HOME"
sudo chmod 751 /home

Comment: @ZDroid, if 777 doesn't work, 755 surely won't help, as it is more restricted.  And the owner certainly does not need to be www-data, and it is recommended by Apache that you **don't** do that.  Apache should normally never own the files it serves. By default, root:root is the owner of the default /var/www, but for a non-public server, the owner can be user:user.  But 755 _is_ the correct permissions for most of the site; Apache, as user www-data, needs read/execute permissions.  Directories within the site that need to be written to can have permissions changed to 777.

Comment: so... what do I do now? :)

Comment: ok apache only needs access to my files folder so I changed ownership to that folder to www-data:www-data.  Can I give apache permission to change anything in user:user folders and limit it to the /home/user/www folder?

Comment: Can you update your answer with the contents of `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default`. You can use `cat /etc/apache2/sites-available/default | pastebinit`. This will make much easier to understand what is the problem.

Comment: sorry if I am slow at this. http://paste.ubuntu.com/1534943/

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar setup in my machine (apache root in home folder). The folder used as apache root (`~/Software/apache_htdocs`) belongs to my user and has 755 permissions (but 777 should work as well). Apache runs with `www-data` user, as default.

The only difference seems to be in `sites-available`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

        DocumentRoot /home/myusername/Software/apache_htdocs
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
            </Directory>

        (... content omitted ...)
</VirtualHost>
```

So try deleting the second `Directory` directive and add `allow from all` on the first. To be safe, before modifying it make a backup of the file. After that restart Apache using `sudo service apache2 restart`.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for reply.  I am still getting the same issue after update.  If I change ownership to www-data:www-data it works, but this just seems like an extra step.